# Upgrade Nvidia driver on windows, ubuntu won't boot

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, nvidia

I have a computer with RTX 3080, which I dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04

I had `nvidia-driver-460` installed on Ubuntu, which worked fine.
Yesterday I updated the driver on Windows through GeForce Experience to 466, after this Ubuntu won't boot.
I didn't change anything on Ubuntu.

I thought that drivers on Windows and Ubuntu are independent and should not affect one another.

I have tried upgrading the driver on Ubuntu, reinstalling, trying older drivers, but nothing works. Ubuntu only boots with `nouveau`, but it doesn't detect my second display.

What can be the problem and what should I do to solve it?

If I uninstall Windows and reinstall Ubuntu only, would that solve the problem or did the driver change the graphics card itself?

EDIT: I have removed `quiet splash` from grub settings to try diagnose the problem, but it won't even show any messages when using nvidia driver.

Comment: What you install on one does not affect the other.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get it working by installing `nvidia-driver-460-server`. I'm not sure whether it is working correctly, but I have both my monitors at correct resolution and `nvidia-smi` is working properly.

I have thought to install server driver because `nvidia-smi` was freezing the computer with normal driver even from root shell.
So I thought to install just the server part to run my AI tasks, but surprisingly after installing server driver I managed to boot successfully.

I'm not sure what is the difference between normal and servers driver, but just happy to get it working at all.

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is that GPUs have a firmware. Maybe it got updated during the drivers update on W10 which broke it for older drivers on your Ubuntu? Just a theory, though. Something like this: https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/nv-uefi-update-x64/

Comment: Most likely, or vBIOS somehow got updated by GeForce Experience. Not sure why on Ubuntu the server driver is working, but normal one doesn't.